# How can I make this method with for loop

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried to writng this code but I think it looks not good :)

Please..
Can I make this method with for loop ? and How?

```
 static public void add_ConstantVote(Contestant [] contestant){
 contestant[0].setVoteScored(8, 0);
 contestant[0].setVoteScored(7, 1);
 contestant[0].setVoteScored(6, 2);
 contestant[0].setVoteScored(9, 3);
 contestant[0].setVoteScored(9, 4);
 contestant[1].setVoteScored(7, 0);
 contestant[1].setVoteScored(10, 1);
 contestant[1].setVoteScored(5, 2);
 contestant[1].setVoteScored(6, 3);
 contestant[1].setVoteScored(7, 4);
 contestant[2].setVoteScored(4, 0);
 contestant[2].setVoteScored(8, 1);
 contestant[2].setVoteScored(6, 2);
 contestant[2].setVoteScored(7, 3);
 contestant[2].setVoteScored(8, 4);
 contestant[3].setVoteScored(6, 0);
 contestant[3].setVoteScored(7, 1);
 contestant[3].setVoteScored(9, 2);
 contestant[3].setVoteScored(8, 3);
 contestant[3].setVoteScored(10, 4);
 }//end of add_ConstantVote
```

Comment: Question is, what exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: I do not see the pattern in the first parameter of the `setVoteScored` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to put first parameter of the setVoteScored method then this example may be help you. One for your constant array another for internal use. For example

```
int[][] values = new int[4][4];

// Assign three elements within it.
values[0][0] = 1;
values[0][1] = 2;
values[0][2] = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
    contestant[i].setVoteScored(values[i][j], j);
  }
}
```

Comment: the first parameter of the setVoteScored method refers to score and the second refers to index of this scores

Comment: @new.programmer How you store your score? means how you are get or you store or any example or any pattern?

Comment: there is no pattern the scores are constant for every contestant

Comment: Then you take store you score in 2 dimension array and get the value within loop